# Is Graphics2D.draw(Shape s) able to draw on the JComponent?

Tags: java, swing

I am using Java 1.7 SDK for drawing Rectangles, Arcs and Ellipses into a JPanel.

The following code does not seem to work:

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1; 

Rectangle area = getBounds(); 
Arc2D.Double shape = new Arc2D.Double(area.x,area.y, area.width,
        area.height, 0, 3.12, Arc2D.PIE); 
g.draw(shape);
```

I checked the documentation for g.draw(shape) and it is implemented as an `abstract` method. Further, I saw that g.fillArc also is implemented as an abstract method. In JDK1.7, do these methods work?

See the following example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GraphicsTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GraphicsTest window = new GraphicsTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GraphicsTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        GraphicsPanel panel = new GraphicsPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        //obtain value of triggering from somewhere code here! 
        String eValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter the value"); 
        panel.triggerGraphing(new Integer(eValue).intValue()); 
    }

    public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel
    {
        int graphType; 

        public GraphicsPanel()
        {
            graphType = 0; 
        }


        void triggerGraphing(int g)
        {
            graphType = g; 
            repaint(); 
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g1)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g1);
            Dimension d = this.getSize();
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;

            switch(graphType){
            case 1:
                drawRect(g, d.width, d.height); 
                break; 
            case 2:
                drawPie(g, d.width, d.height); 
                break;
            }

        }

        void drawRect(Graphics2D g, int w, int h) {
            g.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED); 
            g.fillRect(0,0,w,h); 

        }

        void drawPie(Graphics2D g, int w, int h) {
            g.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLUE); 

            //Arc2D.Double arc = new Arc2D.Double(0,0,w,h,1,30,Arc2D.PIE); 
            g.fillArc(0,0,w,h,1,30);
            //g.draw(arc); 
        }
    }

}
```

The above code finally works, with the help from the community. It appears that the getGraphics() call is very subtle, and needs to be called carefully. Further, in the original code, `area.x` and `area.y` are suspicious elements and appear to mess up the output when used. It is not known as of now, why this is happening.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: No error! Just plain blank panel!

Comment: That means you're probably doing something wrong. You can absolutely use those methods on a JComponent. An abstract method must have an implementation, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the class. The object you're referring to with your 'g' variable is a subclass of Graphics2D that implements those functions.

Comment: In the same method, (I am going to paste the working example soon), I am using a bar chart. The bars are being drawn correctly! If I guage correctly, your answer implies that the fillarc method is not yet implemented?

Comment: That is the opposite of what I'm saying.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those methods certainly do work.

I suspect your problem is the `getBounds()` call. If this returns the bounds of the component, you should ignore the `x` and `y`, as the coordinate system of a component's graphics context is already translated so that (0,0) is the top-left corner of the component. So, use 0 for the x and y of the arc:

```
Arc2D.Double shape = new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, area.width, area.height,
    0, 3.12, Arc2D.PIE);
```

Also make sure that the graphics object is set with a visible color and stroke.